# Install ImageMagick and rmagick on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am trying to install ImageMagick and a ruby library binding for it called rmagick onto a windows machine to use with rails + paperclip. I am currently running windows 7. I have set up the rails environment for the windows machine using the rails installer, if that helps.

I have tried many different resources including these:

[redmine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_install_rmagick_gem_on_Windows)

[rmagick wiki](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki/Installing-on-Windows)

[tutorial](http://phosphor-escence.blogspot.com/2010/10/install-rmagick-on-mingw-and-msys.html)

and i am still getting this error

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-opt-dir="C:\ImageMagick"'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

   current directory: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rmag
ick-2.16.0/ext/RMagick
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170112-3020-wa31th.rb ex
tconf.rb --with-opt-dir="C:\ImageMagick"
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:141:in ``': No such file or directory - identify -version (Errno::ENO
ENT)
        from extconf.rb:141:in `configure_compile_options'
        from extconf.rb:16:in `initialize'
        from extconf.rb:548:in `new'
        from extconf.rb:548:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2
.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86
-mingw32/2.2.0/rmagick-2.16.0/gem_make.out
```

Here is a list of things I have done:

- downloaded the image magick binaries
- installed with path option, and set the C and C++ headers
- added the proper paths (referred to in the wiki) pointing to the download
- installed the `rmagick` gem pointing towards the binary download

Has anyone sucessfully installed imagemagick on windows? I may or may not need to use the `rmagick` gem, as it's just a binding for it, but it seemed like a better option that just the raw download.

If anyone has successfully accomplished this, I would be very appreciative of any help.

It's also worth noting, I am not tied to Paperclip + Imagemagick, if there is another library that works on windows for this I am happy to use that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have installed it. You will need to install Ruby Devkit.
https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

It was very tedious process so I made notes for a client. Steps are mislabelled because it includes installing git and ruby first. I  would use more recent instructions on websites if available.

I think that ImageMagick needed to be version 6, not sure.

Here are the notes:

#### 3. Install devkit

Same link http://rubyinstaller.org/
Download and extract to C:\RubyDevkit

Follow steps 3.1 and 3.2 if you downloaded DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe

For other versions, if you are getting error messages then use instructions from http://rubyinstaller.org/
which used to link to this document:
https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

3.1. Entire DevKit procedure at a glance

- Download matching version (from http://rubyinstaller.org/)
- Uninstall previous version if it exists.
- Extract to C:\RubyDevKit

You need to open CMD.exe (do not use git bash) to C:\RubyDevKit and type these commands.

```
cd C:\RubyDevKit
ruby dk.rb init
ruby dk.rb install
devkitvars.bat
```

#### 4. Install imagemagick

If your ruby is 32 bit, install 32 bit otherwise 64 bit.
What works for sure is `ImageMagick-6.7.3-4-Q16-windows-dll.exe`

**Don't install in `Program Files`** because 3rd party scripts might have problems with spaces.

**Install in `C:\ImageMagick` so that you can copy paste commands later**

**Make sure these options are checked**

- Add application directory to your system path
- Install development headers and libraries for C and C++

### 5. Install rmagick gem

Just running bundle install fails because it requires more options.

Run this from anywhere in `cmd.exe`
To open `cmd.exe` open Start Menu and under `Search programs and files` type `cmd.exe`

```
set CPATH="C:\ImageMagick\include"
set LIBRARY_PATH="C:\ImageMagick\lib"
```

Unfortunately these commands give no visual feedback like OK. To get feedback you can type this:

```
echo %CPATH%
```

And you should get output `"C:\ImageMagick\include"`

```
echo %LIBRARY_PATH%
```

And you should get output `"C:\ImageMagick\lib"`

```
gem install rmagick -- '--with-opt-dir="C:\ImageMagick"'
```

You should get a success message. You can verify if gem is installed by typing

```
gem list
```

It should list rmagick.

Try this first, but in case this doesn't work, look up more current instructions on:
https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki/Installing-on-Windows

Comment: thank you so much! after 2 days of messing around setting it up, that finally worked! much props